# Type Error in Java 7

Tags: java-7

I have a dialog box class that extends JDialog.  One method in this class is this:

```
public char getType()
{
return ((String)fileTypeCombo.getSelectedItem()).charAt(0);
}
```

where fileTypeCombo is this:

```
JComboBox fileTypeCombo = new JComboBox(
            new String[] { "Local", "Shared", "Remote" } );
```

I am getting the following error when I attempt to compile using Java 7:

```
[javac] /home/satin/decodes-8.0/lrgs/gui/NetlistDialog.java:112: error: getType() in NetlistDialog cannot override getType() in Window
[javac]     public char getType()
[javac]                 ^
[javac]   return type char is not compatible with Type
```

It compiles fine with Java 6.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of a method added to the [Window class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) in Java 7.

The super class, `Window`, has `public Window.Type getType()` for the method signature in Java 7. You are attempting to override that method, but are returning a `char` instead of a `Window.Type` object, so a compilation error is occurring.

In [Java 6 that method doesn't exist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html), so you don't get any errors.